# Passing state to a callback in JavaScript an appropriate use of closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

Suppose you want to make an async request in JavaScript, but you want to pass some state along to the callback method. Is the following an appropriate use of closures in JavaScript?

```
function getSomethingAsync(someState, callback) {
    var req = abc.createRequestObject(someParams);
    req.invoke(makeCallback(someState, callback));
}

function makeCallback(someState, callback) {
    return function getSomethingCallback(data) {
        var result = processDataUsingState(data, someState);
        callback(result); // alternately/optionally pass someState along to result
    }
}
```

If not, is there a better or more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any immediate problems with this - closures are powerful for numerous reasons, one of which is removing the need to use global variables for state maintenance.

That said, the only thing you need to be wary of with regards to closures is memory leaks that typically occur in IE, but those are usually, IIRC, related to DOM elements and event handlers attached thereto.

Proceed!

Comment: Good point. Here's a discussion of the IE leak issue: http://laurens.vd.oever.nl/weblog/items2005/closures/

Answer (score 1):

The more idiomatic way is to use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), then you don't need to duplicate the code to create the closure. I'll use a simple example (that doesn't have your custom code) to explain

```
/**
 * Retrieves the content of a url asyunchronously
 * The callback will be called with one parameter: the html retrieved
 */
function getUrl(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({url: url, success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
    }})    
}

// Now lets' call getUrl twice, specifying the same 
// callback but a different id will be passed to each
function updateHtml(id, html) {
    $('#' + id).html(html);
}


// By calling bind on the callback, updateHTML will be called with 
// the parameters you passed to it, plus the parameters that are used
// when the callback is actually called (inside )
// The first parameter is the context (this) to use, since we don't care,
// I'm passing in window since it's the default context
getUrl('/get/something.html', updateHTML.bind(window, 'node1'));
// results in updateHTML('node1', 'response HTML here') being called
getUrl('/get/something-else.html', updateHTML.bind(window, 'node2'));
// results in updateHTML('node2', 'response HTML here') being called
```

`Function.bind` is new so if you need backwards support, look at the Compatibility section of  [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Lastly, I know the question wasn't tagged as jQuery. This was just the quickest way to show an asynchronous function without dealing with cross browser issues

Comment: Nice! Thanks for pointing this out. This, of course, did not exist when I first wrote the question in 2008. Given that it's IE9-only, I think I'll wait a bit before using it ...

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait. The link to MDN has the code you need to make it work in any browser.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the workaround, but it had so many caveats that I left reading about it for another time :-)

Answer (score 0):

its better (nicer) to use anonymous functions:

```
function getSomethingAsync (someState, callback) {
    req.invoke (function (data) {
       var result = processDataUsingState (data, someState);
       callback (result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Javier...why is this better?
Person who downvoted this...why is it not a good answer?

Comment: simply to avoid red-tape: a function call and extra names just to create the closure when you can create it on the spot.  remember that giving a name to a function is simply assigning it to a variable.

Comment: But giving something a name also provides semantics as well as reuse; while your simplification is definitely useful if his makeCallback() function isn't used anywhere else, if it is you would have to then duplicate code. Sometimes it helps readability to break things out into named functions.

Comment: Naming a function makes it easy to read when you're checking out the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can also manipulate the value of "this" in a function with call() / apply().

For example, specify that a further argument to your async method is an object to use as "this" in the callback.  This is how jQuery sets the dom node to be "this" in event callbacks.

```
function getSomethingAsync(callback, scope) {
    var req = abc.createRequestObject(someParams);
    req.invoke(function(rsp) {
      callback.apply(scope, [rsp]);
    });
}

// usage:
getSomethingAsync(function() {console.log(this.someState)}, {someState:'value'});
```